# Is it ok to combine vector addition and scalar multiplication when proving linear transformations?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

So we're on the topic of eigenvectors and this came up the other day.

If $T(c$<sub>1</sub>$v$<sub>1</sub>+$c$<sub>2</sub>$v$<sub>2</sub>$)=c$<sub>1</sub>$T(v$<sub>1</sub>$)+c$<sub>2</sub>$T(v$<sub>2</sub>$)$ for all vectors $v$<sub>1</sub> and $v$<sub>2</sub> in $V$ and scalars $c$<sub>1</sub> and $c$<sub>2</sub>, then $T$ is a linear transformation.

Proving is not really something I have experience with so I'm not sure if this is ok.

Comment: Well $T$ is usually called a linear transformation, when this is the case, but otherwise yes, that is the definition of being a linear transformation

Comment: Oh right, they did say there a typo error. Thanks for all your help, this had us really skeptical.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the condition you've stated is the definition of a linear transform. Since you're confused about that, maybe you've seen an alternate definition which states the following:

- $T(av) = aT(v)$ for every scalar $a$ and vector $v \in V$
- $T(v + w) = T(v) + T(w)$ for every pair of vectors $v, w \in V$

It can be seen the condition given in your question implies the above. Set $c_1 = a$ and $c_2 = 0$ first and then, $c_1 = c_2 = 1.$
In fact, the two conditions are equivalent, it should be easy to see how the above definition implies the conditions given in your question.

Answer (score -1):

We say a map ϕ : X → Y between two vector spaces X, Y is called a linear map if the
following holds:

ϕ(λ·$x_1$+µ·$x_2$) =λ·ϕ($x_1$)+µ·ϕ($x_2$) for all vectors $x_1$, $x_2$ in X and real numbers λ, µ.